# Any way to tighten up a loose tooth?

Tags: prevention

Once a tooth is a little loose, is that it?

Or is there some way to tighten it up again?

Vitamins, Herbal remedies, or any other pearls of wisdom, welcome....

Comment: Why is it loose? Knocked loose? Gum disease? You're going to need a dentist if you want to keep the tooth.

Answer (score 3):

If the mobility of the tooth is due to trauma, the prognosis is incertain in permanent teeth. This [paper](http://www.aapd.org/media/Policies_Guidelines/G_trauma.pdf), is very well detailed as to different levels of trauma. Mobility usually occurs after the extrusion of the tooth:

> Extrusion
>   Definition: partial displacement of the tooth axially from
>   the socket; partial avulsion. The periodontal ligament usually
>   is torn.
>   Diagnosis: Clinical findings reveal that the tooth appears
>   elongated and is mobile. Radiographic findings reveal an increased
>   periodontal ligament space apically.
>
> In permanent
>   mature teeth with closed apices, there is considerable risk
>   for pulp necrosis and pulp canal obliteration. These teeth
>   must be followed carefully.

In the futur, a tooth which has suffered from an extrusion might require a root canal if an infection of the apex develops, though it might remain loose even so.

If the loosening of the tooth is caused by a [gum disease](http://www.nidcr.nih.gov/oralhealth/Topics/GumDiseases/PeriodontalGumDisease.htm#deep), such as periodontitis, it may be possible. The earlier it is detected, the better the results.

The first step is to make sure that oral hygiene at home is on point: daily flossing and brushing. A chart will be made to take measurements of the gum surrounding the tooth and determine to what extent it is affected with periodontitis. Deep cleaning of the gum and planing of the root will be made to ensure that no traces of tartar or plaque is left behind, as they contribute to the inflammation and progress of the disease.

> Scaling means scraping off the tartar from above and below the gum line. Root planing gets rid of rough spots on the tooth root where the germs gather, and helps remove bacteria that contribute to the disease. In some cases a laser may be used to remove plaque and tartar. This procedure can result in less bleeding, swelling, and discomfort compared to traditional deep cleaning methods.

When these methods are inefficient, or in more advanced stages of the disease, more complex surgical treatments might be necessary, for example flap surgery or bone grafts. You can read about those more in depth [here](http://www.nidcr.nih.gov/oralhealth/Topics/GumDiseases/PeriodontalGumDisease.htm#deep).